# methods to call a model name on Controller's

Tags: cakephp, plugins, model, controller

I am freshman of CakePHP...
Is there any methods to call a model name on Controller's?
Lets say i have 3 Model - User,Group,Widget..
and 3 Controller - UsersController, GroupsController, WidgetsController..
Actually i plan to write a plugin .. which set the `<title>` for both view file.

Something like .. 
i use plugin to set `<title><?php echo $model_name; ?></title>`
And when i move to '/users/main' then the title would be `<title>User</title>`,
when i move to '/widgets/main' then the title would be `<title>Widget</title`>.

Any Idea with this solution ?
How to each Controller's can match with it's own Model_name?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

in your template:

```
<title><?php echo $title_for_layout?></title>
```

Add this to your controller:

```
$this->pageTitle = $model_name;
```

Comment: Note that the 'automatic' `$title_for_layout` variable is marked deprecated in CakePHP 2.3. Afaik `pageTitle` is not used anywhere by CakePHP? It's best to manually set `$title_for_layout` Or another viewVar.

Answer (score 1):

To have the modelName automatically present in every view, add this code to your AppController;

```
public function beforeRender()
{
    parent::beforeRender();

    // modelClass should be set automatically
    // to the 'default' model for the controller
    $this->set('model_name', $this->modelClass);
}
```

And inside your views:

```
<title><?php echo __($model_name); ?></title>
```